# Merging (intersecting) more than two posting list in linear time

Tags: text-mining, information-retrieval

The intersecting algorithm for two posting lists implemented below:

```
def intersection(A, B):
    a, b = len(A), len(B)
    i , j = 0, 0
    result = []
    while i < a and j < b:
        if A[i] == B[j]:
            result.append(A[i])
            i += 1
            j += 1
        elif A[i] < B[j]:
            i += 1
        else:
            j += 1
    return result

A = [1, 2, 4, 11, 31, 45, 173, 174]
B = [2, 31, 54, 101, 174]
intersection(A, B) #returns [2, 31, 174]
```

**Brief description of the algorithm:**

For the given posting lists, it starts from the first index of both array `A` and `B`. Then it compares the documents:

1. If `A[i]` equals to `B[j]`: Add `A[i]` (or `B[j]`) to result and then increment both `i` and `j` by one.
2. If `A[i]` is greater than `B[j]`: Increment `j` by one.
3. If `A[i]` is lower than `B[j]`: Increment `i` by one.

If we consider the length m, n for `A` and `B` the time complexity of this algorithm would be $O(m + n)$.

**Problem Description:**

Suppose that we have more than two arrays. Is it possible two do this is linear time?

**P.S:** A good approach is that we start with increasing length order of arrays. but the actual question is about the time complexity.